# Assigning a variable to a href/button

Tags: php, html, css, button, href

I am trying to make a login form for a website for a school project.

When a certain username and password is entered it can then go through to the next page, The part that I am having trouble with is figuring out whether I can assign a variable to a `href` or `button`.

for example, the `href` has the variable of 'A' and the password input has a variable of 'B' and there is a php code saying:

```
If (B == ('Qwerty')) then
  A == 'google.com';
else
 echo ('Wrong password')
```

I know this example code is probably done wrong but if anyone understands what I am trying to ask/do, can you help.
If this helps here is what I have.

```
<div class="col-md-4  form-group" data-for="password">
        <label for="password-form1-2" class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="email" data-form-field="password" required="required" class="form-control display-7" id="password-form1-2" placeholder="qwerty">
</div>                       
      <div class="col-md-12 input-group-btn align-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form display-4" onclick="window.location.href = '2after login.php';">Log in</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think you need a `<form action="2after login.php">` rather you code the url in button onclick event

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Brickowiski , but that did not really change anything, I am looking for it to not proceed to the next page when nothing is entered into the form

Comment: Regarding your question "whether I can assign a variable to a href or button.". What kind of variable you want to assign, and by assigning the variable what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to post information from one page to another, first of all, the simplest way:

index.html

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your username" required><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
```

login.php

```php
<?php

$username = $_POST[ "username" ];
$password = $_POST[ "password" ];
$expected_password = "password123";

if ( $password == $expected_password ) {

    echo "Passwords match!";

} else {

    echo "Incorrect password!";

}
```

This will **post** the form values to **login.php** (specified in the action attribute of the form). You will be directed to `/login.php` in your browser and will see one of two messages - either the "password" entered matched the "password" expected, or you receive and "incorrect password" message.

Note that the password would clearly not be hardcoded in a real application, this is simply to demonstrate how to post information from one page to another.

---

Using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started):

index.html

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="my-form">

  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your username" required><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">

</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script src="form.js"></script>
```

form.js

```js
let form = document.querySelector( "#my-form" );
let output = document.querySelector( "#output" );

form.addEventListener( "submit", function( e ) {

  e.preventDefault();

  let formData = new FormData( form );
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {

      output.innerHTML = this.responseText;

    }

  }

  xhr.open( "post", "login.php" );
  xhr.send( formData );

});
```

This will post the values of the form to `login.php` and send the information back, without reloading the page or navigating away. The response from `login.php` above will then be shown inside the output `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks Danny, the PHP version was what I was looking for but I have already found the solution

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two methods of going about this.  One is the Javascript way, which utilizes "onclick=...." and the other is the HTML Form post method.  You need to have your inputs inside a form for that.  You're going to need to learn Javascript anyways.  So here's a perfect place to start.

```
<div class="col-md-4  form-group" data-for="password">
        <label for="password-form1-2" class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="email" data-form-field="password" required="required" class="form-control display-7" id="password-form1-2" placeholder="qwerty">
</div>                       
<div class="col-md-12 input-group-btn align-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form display-4" onclick="validateEntry()">Log in</button>
        <a id="result"></a>
</div>



<script>    
function validateEntry(){
  var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("password-form1-2").value);
  if (!password || 0 === password.length){
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Nothing entered.  Please, enter a password';
  }else{
    login(password);
  }
}

function login(password) {
  var fail = true;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var fail = false;
      if (this.responseText == "Updated"){
          window.location.href = "wizard17.php";
      }else{
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }  

    }else{
      window.setTimeout(failed(fail), 5000);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "login.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("password="+password);
}

function failed(fail){
      if(fail){
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Connection Failed.';
      }
}

</script>
```

The simple form post method (as follows) does not have the ability for the same kind of responsiveness:

```
<div class="col-md-4  form-group" data-for="password">
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <label for="password" class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" data-form-field="password" required="required" class="form-control display-7" id="password" placeholder="qwerty">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form display-4">Log in</button>  <!--notice that onclick is not used here -->
        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you should do, is redirect in your login php file after check credentials.

You must do the matching to know the url and then, at the end insert this:

```
header('Location: '. $url);
exit;
```

That would redirect